# Ayuda en JNI Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jni

¿Me podrían ayudar al compilar el [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc) para *JNI* en *Ubuntu*? Lo que pasa es que al crear el *".so"*, y compilar llamando las librerías necesarias,en mi caso (por la versión de Java que uso)...

```
gcc -shared -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux/ -o libHolaMundo.so HolaMundo.c -Wall
```

... me sale el error de que:

> In file included from HolaMundo.c:3:0:
>
> HolaMundo.h:2:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
>
> `#include <jni.h>`

Comment: ¿ya revisaste la ruta de instalación del JDK que sea la correcta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usar JNI por primera vez puede ser un tanto complicado, yo te recomiendo usar JNA. Desde JNA puedes llamar a codigo nativo sin necesidad de recompilar el ejecutable ni modificarlo.

Te doy un ejemplo con JNA:

Código en C:

```
#include  //se usa la entrada por defecto stdio.h

void helloFromC() {
    printf("Hello from C!\n");
}
```

Para compilar:
gcc -o libctest.so -shared ctest.c

Para usar esta librería desde Java:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class HelloWorld {
    public interface CTest extends Library {
        public void helloFromC();
    }

    static public void main(String argv[]) {
        CTest ctest = (CTest) Native.loadLibrary("ctest", CTest.class);
        ctest.helloFromC();
    }
}
```

Más informacion:

[Página del proyecto JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna)

[JNA: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access)

En cuanto a tu problema:
El compilador no pudo encontrar el archivo de cabecera jni.h, colocala en la carpeta de cabeceras y recompila.